# ios simulator why div seem less wide

Tags: ios, iphone, simulator

the image: iphone 320x480 (not retina) with ios 6.1.

The blue div size: w:640px h:480px.

my mac: macbook air 13 inch.

the question: why the blue div is less width than the device width?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's mobile Safari being clever and zooming out so you can see the full width of the webpage–I expect the behaviour is not unique to the simulator. You can alter that behaviour using the viewport meta tag. You can [read all about that here](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html).